# PHP preg_match_all large string into groups with incrementing keys => values

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all

Running PHP 7.1.5, I have a long string output that I'm grouping with `preg_match_all`. I am trying to get each output group into a new array `key => value`.  For example, I have a long string like this:

```
$string = (
Name: John Doe
Address: 123 Main St
City: Chicago
State: IL
Zip: 60021
Name: Jane Smith
Address: 123 State Ave
City: Boston
State: MA
Zip: 02501
Name: John Doe
Address: 123 Main St
City: Chicago
State: IL
Zip: 60021
)
```

`preg_match_all('!(Name.*|Address.*|City.*|State.*|Zip.*)!', $string, $results);`

This extracts the information, however, It's all contained in the `$results` array under one key.  Instead of this output:

```
Array (
0 =>
    [0] => Name: John Doe
    [1] => Address: 123 Main St
    [2] => City: Chicago
    [3] => State: IL
    [4] => Zip: 60021
    [5] => Name: Jane Smith
    [6] => Address: 123 State Ave
    [7] => City: Boston
    [8] => State: MA
    [9] => Zip: 02501
    [10] => Name: John Doe
    [11] => Address: 123 Main St
    [12] => City: Chicago
    [13] => State: IL
    [14] => Zip: 60021
)
```

I need this output in the array for every capture group:

```
Array (
    [0] =>
        [0]Name: John Doe
        [1]Address: 123 Main St
        [2]City: Chicago
        [3]State: IL
        [4]Zip: 60021

    [1] =>
        [0]Name: Jane Smith
        [1]Address: 123 State Ave
        [2]City: Boston
        [3]State: MA
        [4]Zip: 02501

     [2] =>
        [0]Name: John Doe
        [1]Address: 123 Main St
        [2]City: Chicago
        [3]State: IL
        [4]Zip: 60021
)
```

As you can see, the first and third entries are identical, and I have a lot of repeat entries. I can solve this by running an `array_unique($results)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data has a known quantity of subelements in it (in this case, 5), you can use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
<?php
$string = "
Name: John Doe
Address: 123 Main St
City: Chicago
State: IL
Zip: 60021
Name: Jane Smith
Address: 123 State Ave
City: Boston
State: MA
Zip: 02501
Name: John Doe
Address: 123 Main St
City: Chicago
State: IL
Zip: 60021";
preg_match_all('!(Name.*|Address.*|City.*|State.*|Zip.*)!', $string, $results);
$records = array_chunk($results[0], 5);
var_dump($records);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/E7L2O)

And if you don't know how many elements there will be, but can assume they all will have the same, you can count how many keys there are, and then use that number:

```
<?php
$string = "
Name: John Doe
Address: 123 Main St
City: Chicago
State: IL
Zip: 60021
Name: Jane Smith
Address: 123 State Ave
City: Boston
State: MA
Zip: 02501
Name: John Doe
Address: 123 Main St
City: Chicago
State: IL
Zip: 60021";
preg_match_all('!(Name.*|Address.*|City.*|State.*|Zip.*)!', $string, $results);
$records = $results[0];
$keys = [];
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $recordArray = explode(":", $record); // $recordArray[0] will have the key
    if (in_array($recordArray[0], $keys)) break; // if key exists, we started a new record
    $keys[] = $recordArray[0];
}
$records = array_chunk($records, count($keys));
var_dump($records);
```

Finally, if the number of elements is variable among different users, then you can set a fixed "last element" and stop the user array when it's found:

```
// $string
preg_match_all('!(Name.*|Address.*|City.*|State.*|Zip.*)!', $string, $results);
$records = $results[0];
$finalResults = [];
$lastElement = "Zip";
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $result[] = $record;
    $recordArray = explode(":", $record);
    if ($recordArray[0] === $lastElement) {
        $finalResults[] = $result;
        $result = [];
    }
}
var_dump($finalResults);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/bU4EA)

Comment: Thank you for this. It works. Do you have a way to designate the `Zip` as the last key in the array, and the next key will be the new array key?

I can see this solving the trouble of having a second address line, which would throw off `array_chunk`.

Comment: The second example should address (pun not intended) that. It will calculate what the length of each array should be by searching when a key repeats.

Comment: You have a good answer, but after running a few tests, unfortunately, it didn't work. Often times there's a second address line and that throws everything off.

Anything else you can think of?

Comment: @INA2N I added a solution that takes into account a variable number of elements per user.